Drawing a cursor issues
I have been trying to make some basic 2D cnc like simulator, with some rectangle that is shaped by tools etc. I want to make cursor, so the user know where the current position of tool is.
But I don't know how to do it. I tried to make function to save the current points colour, then to draw the cursor and then to fill these pixels with saved colours, but this is very buggy and slow.
I also tried to make another bitmap that is transparent, but I also failed. So how to manage to write cursor that have X and Y coordinated and does not interfere with object already drawn on canvas?
Thanks for any advice, I am very much a beginner (4 months)

It's not quite clear what you want to achieve. Would like you use a colored bitmap with transparency as a Windows cursor? If so, you can use this method from this NuGet package (disclaimer: I am the author).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68224533/14171304 Link to c# version in the comments.
